# WSDL restrictions does not work

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i try to create a simple webservice. Everything works fine, but the restrictions which I defined in wsdl does not work.

I try two types of restriction: minLength/maxLength and enumeration. It doesn't matter which data I send from client, everything is accepted...

Here are my code:

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
              xmlns:tns="http://localhost/APItest"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
              xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              targetNamespace="http://localhost/APItest">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://localhost/APItest">

        <xsd:element name="HelloRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:element name="name">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:minLength value="5"/>
              <xsd:maxLength value="8"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element> 

        <xsd:element name="car">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value="Audi"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="Golf"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="BMW"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element> 

                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="HelloResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="time" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>


<wsdl:message name="Hello">
    <wsdl:part name="input" element="tns:HelloRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="HelloResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="output" element="tns:HelloResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="APIPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="Hello">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:Hello"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:HelloResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="APIHttpBinding" type="tns:APIPortType">
    <http:binding verb="POST"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Hello">
        <http:operation location="API/Hello"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content part="Hello" type="text/xml"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content part="Hello" type="text/xml"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="API">
    <wsdl:port name="APIHttpport" binding="tns:APIHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://localhost/APItest/server.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

server.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

// Disable WSDL Cache
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

class API
{
    public function Hello($params)
    {

    $response = new stdClass();
    $response->result = "Hello " . $params->name . ", your car is '" . $params->car . "'!";
    $response->time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    file_put_contents("logs/log_" . date("Ymd-His") . "_ERROR.txt", print_r($this, true));

    return $response;
    }

}

//create a new SOAP server
$server = new SoapServer("API.wsdl");

//attach the API class to the SOAP Server
$server->setClass('API');

//start the SOAP requests handler
$server->handle();
```

client.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

// Disable WSDL Cache
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

$wsdl = "API.wsdl";

$options = array(
    'trace' => true,
    'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
);

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$input = new stdClass();
$input->name = "MartinMartinMartinMartin";
$input->car = "Ford";

try {
    $hello = $soapClient->Hello($input);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($hello, true) . '</pre>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<h3>Error calling last Request!</h3>";
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($e, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: It seems, that the php soap server do not check out the box. So I try to validate against xsd, but this is also not working: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258077/validation-of-soap-xml-against-xsd-does-not-work]. It would be nice If there is anyone out there, which can help.