# Validation of Soap-XML against XSD does not work

Tags: php, xml, validation, soap, xsd

since a lot of days i try to validate a soap requst xml against my xsd, but with no success:

This is my XML (generated by PHP-Soap-Client):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/APItest" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:Hello env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
            <input xsi:type="ns1:HelloRequest">
                <name xsi:type="ns1:name">MartinMartinMartinMartin</name>
                <car xsi:type="ns1:car">Ford</car>
            </input>
        </ns1:Hello>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And this is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://localhost/APItest"
            xmlns="http://localhost/APItest"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="HelloRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="name">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="5"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="8"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>

                <xsd:element name="car">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Audi"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Golf"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="BMW"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="HelloResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="time" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

I am using the xsd validation tool on:
http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation
There I got error:

> Not valid.
>   Error - Line 2, 255: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 255; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'env:Envelope'.
>   Error - Line 5, 36: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 36; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ns1:HelloRequest' to a type definition for element 'input'.
>   Error - Line 6, 27: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 27; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ns1:name' to a type definition for element 'name'.
>   Error - Line 7, 25: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 25; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ns1:car' to a type definition for element 'car'.

I also try the [xml->schemaValidate function in php](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.schemavalidate.php). Here I got:

> Error 1845: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

After reading a lot of results in google I found, that I have to import the envelope schema:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

But than, the validation tool returns:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - access denied (&quot;java.net.SocketPermission&quot; &quot;schemas.xmlsoap.org:80&quot; &quot;connect,resolve&quot;)</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>access denied (&quot;java.net.SocketPermission&quot; &quot;schemas.xmlsoap.org:80&quot; &quot;connect,resolve&quot;)</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (&quot;java.net.SocketPermission&quot; &quot;schemas.xmlsoap.org:80&quot; &quot;connect,resolve&quot;)
java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:510)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.&lt;init&gt;(HttpClient.java:211)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2179)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2082)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1012)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:623)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:572)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:638)
info.utilitiesonline.backend.rest.XSDController.validateXSD(XSDController.java:70)
info.utilitiesonline.backend.rest.XSDController.validateXML(XSDController.java:106)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:909)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:857)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:811)
com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249)</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.54</h3></body></html>
```

So, I have no idea what I have to do, to solve the issue... I am looking forward to get your hints.

thanks in advance

Comment: I have some issue. Did you fix it? @Martin

Comment: Hi @maverabil, the problem was 6 years ago and I have no idea or does not remember the solution. Sorry.